# Problemas con JQuery y validacion

Tags: jquery

Al querer validar un formulario en donde quiero que una matricula inicie con un 1 no me ejecuta nada, les adjunto el código.

**JQUERY**

```
function verificarMatricula () {
  var matricula = $('#matricula').val()

  if (matricula.length > 0) {
    if (matricula[0] != 1) {
      $('#mat').html('La matricula debe de iniciar con 1')
    } else {
      $('#mat').html('')
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#matricula').keyup(verificarMatricula)
})
```

**HTML**

```
    <form action="datosre.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar2();" name="formulario">
        <div class="grid">
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <input id="_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="_Apaterno" name="Apaterno" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido Paterno"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="_Amaterno" name="Amaterno" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido Materno"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="matricula _email" autocomplete="off" name="email" type="text" value="" minlength="11"
                maxlength="11" placeholder="Ingresa tu matricula">
            <div id="mat" class="validacion"></div>
            <input id="_password2" name="_password2" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
            <input id="_verpass" name="_verpass" type="password" placeholder="Verifica tu contraseña">
            <div id="comprobar" class="contra validacion"></div>

            <button> Enviar </button>
            <a href="index.php">Iniciar sesion</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola, define el id correcto que es usado en la función verificarMatricula, debe ser  <input id="matricula", revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe principalmente a el id que defines en el input a validar, tienes  `id="matricula _email"`:

```
  <input id="matricula _email" autocomplete="off" name="email" type="text" value="" minlength="11"
                maxlength="11" placeholder="Ingresa tu matricula">
```

debe ser  `id="matricula"`  :

```
    <input id="matricula" autocomplete="off" name="matricula" type="text" value="" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Ingresa tu matricula">
```

Realiza el cambio y se realizará correctamente el llamado a la función  `verificarMatricula()`  Revisa tu ejemplo:

```js
function verificarMatricula() {

  var matricula = $('#matricula').val()

  if (matricula.length > 0) {
    if (matricula[0] != 1) {
      $('#mat').html('La matricula debe de iniciar con 1')
    } else {
      $('#mat').html('')
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#matricula').keyup(verificarMatricula)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="datosre.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar2();" name="formulario">
        <div class="grid">
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <input id="_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="_Apaterno" name="Apaterno" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido Paterno"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="_Amaterno" name="Amaterno" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido Materno"
                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <input id="matricula" autocomplete="off" name="matricula" type="text" value="" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Ingresa tu matricula"> 
            <div id="mat" class="validacion"></div>
            <input id="_password2" name="_password2" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
            <input id="_verpass" name="_verpass" type="password" placeholder="Verifica tu contraseña">
            <div id="comprobar" class="contra validacion"></div>

            <button> Enviar </button>
            <a href="index.php">Iniciar sesion</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me permito modificar el codigo por funciones un poco mas claras, la condición es que si matricula esta vacía o no inicia con 1, muestra el mensaje.

```
function verificarMatricula () {
  var matricula = $(this).val();
  var message = '';
  //Se realiza la comparación con una cadena vacía
  if (matricula === '' || !matricula.startsWith('1')) {
    message = 'La matricula debe iniciar con 1';
  }

  $('#mat').html(message);
}

$(() => {
  $('#matricula').on('keyup', verificarMatricula);
})
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Puedes comprobar con la respuesta editada?